# Python 3 doesnt show zfill function when i type

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=12345
print(x.zfill(10))
```

I'm new to this and was practicing, got to zfill function, and tried using it but when I type ".zfill" it doesn't work. it's like the function doesn't exist.

Comment: I recommend learning to check the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill

Answer (score 2):

`zfill` is a method of strings, not integers:

```
x = 12345
print(str(x).zfill(10))
```

Comment: Or `print(f'{x:010}')`...